# Intel® Wireless-AC 9462 is not giving link speed more than 150mbps

Tags: wireless-router

I have a MSI GV62 8RE. It comes with Intel® Wireless-AC 9462 which is supposed to give me a max speed of 433mbps(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-9462-brief.html). But I am getting only a speed of 150mbps

Comment: Are you getting more on other devices connected to same router? If not, talk to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Your Intel Wireless-AC 9462 can only use its max 433Mbps PHY rate when it's talking to an AC-capable AP (wireless router). When talking to a non-AC AP, or when only talking to the 2.4GHz radio of a dual-band AP, it's limited to 150Mbps as its max PHY rate, and in some common cases may even be limited to just 72.2Mbps.

So, upgrade your AP to one that supports AC, and if your AP is using separate network names (SSIDs) for the 2.4GHz vs. 5GHz network, make sure your PC is set to join the AC-capable 5GHz network.